# Flutter on VS Code issue: StreamController.Sink.add() suddenly require argument PUSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, stream, flutter, bloc

Good afternoon good people,
I'm suddenly experiencing a problem with VS Code:
in a couple of Flutter apps Streamcontroller.sink.add();
suddenly require the argument "push" (before it didn't).
[image: live]

without adding the push argument obviously it return the error

```
2 required argument(s) expected, but 1 found.dart(not_enough_required_arguments)
```

Does anyone know what might have happened?
thank you in advance for your help
Francesco

edit: via f12 the definition actually shows the argument push

```
    part of dart.core;

/**
 * A generic destination for data.
 *
 * Multiple data values can be put into a sink, and when no more data is
 * available, the sink should be closed.
 *
 * This is a generic interface that other data receivers can implement.
 */
abstract class Sink<T> {
  /**
   * Adds [data] to the sink.
   *
   * Must not be called after a call to [close].
   */
  void add(T data, Future push);

  /**
   * Closes the sink.
   *
   * The [add] method must not be called after this method.
   *
   * Calling this method more than once is allowed, but does nothing.
   */
  void close();
}
```

but as pskink reminded the documentation doesn't show this requirement;
I don't have idea how this can have changed,
at this point the question is:

how do I restore it to normality?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/EventSink/add.html - its version `1.0.0`

Comment: yes it is, it was also a couple of days ago and everything worked fine

Comment: so what compilation error yo you have if you write `sinkObj.add(data);`?

Comment: adding 'only' data to the sink.add I get an error, which specify that an argument is missing; the missing arguments appears to be Future push;
it wasn't required before and, as you underlined, isn't required in the documentation. So my guess is something inadvertently tampered with the dart.core, in that case how do I restore it to normality?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/sink.dart - i have no idea what version of dart you have

Comment: I have 1.0.0, clearly something went wrong, any idea how I can restore it to normal?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted. Perhaps you inadvertently modified source in the Flutter install directory.

Comment: thank you Gunter! it worked
if you make it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR
what appeared to be bad code,
was instead corrupted dart code;

I followed the [instruction](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted) provide by Gunter
and everything went back to normal.

Thanks again Gunter